# java Pause code and wait for user input

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, jpanel

I wrote my program in two parts, I wrote the actual functionality first, and then the GUI to display it all.
I need to wait/pause for a user to click a "Done" button from another class(DisplayImages) before continuing executing code.
My DisplayImages class takes a list of MyImage. The images are then displayed in a jpanel and the user selects a couple of images
and then clicks a 'Done' button. How can I wait for a response or something like that?

```
public class One{

    ArrayList<MyImage> images = new ArrayList<MyImage>();

    public One(){
        DisplayImages displayOne = new DisplayImages(images);
        displayOne.run();
        //I need to pause/wait here until the user has pressed the done button
        //in the DisplayImages class

        images.clear();
        images = displayOne.getSelectedImages();

        //do stuff here with images arrylist
        }
}
```

DisplayImages class

```
public class DisplayImages extends JFrame{
    private ArrayList<MyImage> images = new ArrayList<MyImage>();
    private ArrayList<MyImage> selectedImages = new ArrayList<MyImage>();

    public DisplayImages(ArrayList<MyImage> images){
        this.images = images;
    }

    public void run(){
        //code creates a jpanel and displays images along with a done button

        //user presses done button
        done.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                selectedImages = getSelectedImages();
                //here I would send a signal to continue running in class One
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<MyImage> getSelectedImages(){
        //code returns list of all the images the user selected on JPanel
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you need to open and process the dialog in the same method then using the dialog approach suggested with `JOptionPane` seems fine. However this seems bad design (opening a frame and waiting for input in a constructor?). I would prefer an approach similar to the one below (please read my inline comments):

```
public class One {

    ArrayList<MyImage> images = new ArrayList<MyImage>();

    public One() {
        // perform only initialization here
    }

    // call this method to create the dialog that allows the user to select images
    public void showDialog() {
        DisplayImages displayOne = new DisplayImages(images);

        // pass a reference to this object so DisplayImages can call it back
        displayOne.run(this);
    }

    // this will be called by the action listener of DisplayImages when Done is clicked
    public void processSelectedImages(List<MyImage> selectedImages) {
        images.clear();
        images = selectedImages;

        // do stuff here with images arrylist
    }
}


public class DisplayImages {
    ...
    public void run(final One callback){  // Note that now a reference to the caller is passed
         // creates jpanel and displays images along with a done button

         // user presses done button
         done.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 setVisible(false);
                 selectedImages = getSelectedImages();

                 // here is how we can send a signal to notify the caller
                 callback.processSelectedImages(selectedImages); 
             }
         });
    }
    ...
}
```

As a side note please do not name your methods `run()` if you are not implementing the `Runnable` interface and/or using threads. This is very confusing

Comment: +1 Of course a listener is better than my suggestion but I wanted to keep it easy.

Comment: This looks like something I might use. I might have to use Reflection since public void run(final One callback) is hardcoded to accept only type One classes but I will need other classes calling run.

Comment: @Miss_poker You could make all the classes like `One` implement an interface (let's say `Caller`) that would have one method `public void processSelectedImages(List<MyImage> selectedImages)`. Then `DisplayImages.run()` would change to `public void run(final Caller caller)`. If this is still not good enough for you please edit your question to provide clarifications about your restrictions

Answer (score 1):

That is quite easy, some people here are thinking to complicated. You will need no multithreading, you just need a modal dialog. [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) provides easy access to them.

I modified your code:

```
public class One{

    ArrayList<MyImage> images = new ArrayList<MyImage>();

    public One(){
        DisplayImages displayOne = new DisplayImages(images);
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, displayOne);

        if (n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
          //I need to pause/wait here until the user has pressed the done button
          //in the DisplayImages class

          images = displayOne.getSelectedImages();

          //do stuff here with images arrylist
          }
        }
}
```

MyImage class

```
public class DisplayImages extends JPanel{
    private ArrayList<MyImage> images = new ArrayList<MyImage>();

    public DisplayImages(ArrayList<MyImage> images){
        this.images = images;

        //code creates a jpanel and displays images along with a done button
    }

    public ArrayList<MyImage> getSelectedImages(){
        //code returns list of all the images the user selected on JPanel
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use threading.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Then you can set up each instance on a separate thread, and either use the built in `Object.notify and Object.wait`

Or have yourself a global flag variable, static, available to both classes, which you change to notify the other class that the done button was clicked.